# Java encrypt/decript data from PHP to Java, IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: java, php, aes, encryption

I'm trying to read a base64 encoded and AES 128-bit encrypted string from PHP, but I'm getting IllegalBlockSizeException.

PHP encrypt:

```
encrypt("My f awesome test !");

function encrypt($string){
    $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', "1cc251f602cf49f2");

    mcrypt_generic_init($td, "f931c96c4a4e7e47", "1cc251f602cf49f2");
    $enc = mcrypt_generic($td, $string);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);

    return base64_encode($enc);
}
```

And the returned value is:

> McBeY73GQ5fawxIunVKpqUupipeRlt9ntyMRzjbPfTI=

Now I want to read it in Java:

```
static public String decrypt(String data) throws Exception {
   data = new String( Base64.decode(data, Base64.NO_WRAP) );

   byte[] keyByte = "f931c96c4a4e7e47".getBytes("UTF-8");
   byte[] ivByte = "1cc251f602cf49f2".getBytes("UTF-8");

   Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");
   IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);
   Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
   c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
   byte[] bval = c.doFinal( data.getBytes("UTF-8") );

   return new String( bval );
}
```

And I'm getting an Exception:

> javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: data not block size aligned

This might be caused by padding?

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Why is cipher set to decrypt mode? Also should specify exactly where the error is thrown and what the input was for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Your error was caused by the conversion of the plaintext to and from a string. It's not necessary anyway - just use byte arrays:

```
byte[] data = Base64
    .decodeBase64("McBeY73GQ5fawxIunVKpqUupipeRlt9ntyMRzjbPfTI=");
byte[] keyByte = "f931c96c4a4e7e47".getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] ivByte = "1cc251f602cf49f2".getBytes("UTF-8");

Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivByte);
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
byte[] bval = c.doFinal(data);

System.out.println(new String(bval)); // Prints My f awesome test !
```

I recommend you use padding in your encryption, otherwise you cannot cope with arbitrarily-sized input.

Comment: Thanks for your helping, now it's working but I'm getting some extra chars. I have edited my post!

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian I'm guessing the PHP code is using [zero padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Zero_padding)? I suggest you try and find a way to get the PHP code to do something like PKCS5 padding.

Answer (score 1):

the IllegalBlockSizeException thrown on call to doFinal() if: "cipher is a block cipher, no padding has been requested (only in encryption mode), and the total input length of the data processed by this cipher is not a multiple of block size; or if this encryption algorithm is unable to process the input data provided." -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal%28%29. So its either bad input data or block size.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version of encryption/decryption between

https://github.com/chaudhuri-ab/CrossPlatformCiphers

Hope this helps someone as it took me a while to work through the little details between the platforms.